# Replace all colon character that does not occur after specific word pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, regex-negation, replaceall

For a given text like

> pack: my box with five: dozen: liquor: jugs ::: :

I want to replace all the `:` with `;` that occur only after the words ack and zen. So the output I expect here is

> pack: my box with five; dozen: liquor; jugs ;;; ;

Note that `:` after ack and zen are untouched whereas everything else is replaced.

Please help me. I am only able to match `(ack|zen):`. This is only giving me the matches `ack:` and `zen:`. I dont know how to negate this and construct a regex.

Note: I am using Ruby.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby, but a simple Googling: `sentence.gsub! 'ack:', 'ack;'` should work :/

Comment: i guess i asked the question wrong, see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look-behind here and use `gsub`:

```
puts "pack: my box with five: dozen: liquor: jugs ::: :".gsub(/(?<!ack|zen):/, ";")
```

[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/LAqX9Q)

Results:

```
pack: my box with five; dozen: liquor; jugs ;;; ;
```

You can use the look-behind here because both the parts are of the same size (3 chars).

Answer (score 2):

Use negative lookbehind for replacement.

Search for:

```
(?<!ack|zen):
```

Replace by:

```
;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT0iH5/2)

`(?<!ack|zen):` is a negative lookbehind which means match a colon only if it is NOT preceded by `ack` or `zen`.

Comment: sorry, i edited the question. i needed the inverse of what i asked.

Answer (score 2):

You need a lookbehind as explained at [Regular-Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

This works:

```
(?<=(ack|zen)):
```

You can test it here: https://www.debuggex.com/.

Comment: Nice and fast, however, I would not set a capturing group inside the look-behind, it is additional unnecessary overhead. I re-formatted the answer to look better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind with two fixed strings:

```
(?<!ack|zen):
```

To simplify the regex engine work, you can test this too:

```
:(?<!ack:|zen:)
```

*(with this last pattern, the two branches of the lookbehind are only tested at positions with an hyphen instead of for each positions in the string for the first pattern.)*